# Shifting origin in plots using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame in pandas and I am plotting a scatter plot between two columns of the data frame,Now I want to transform the origin from (0,0) to say (1300,50) in this scatter plot.I am using Jupyter IPython notebook on ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xlim` and `ylim`, and provide either a `tuple` as `(lower, upper)` or an `int` as lower limit only:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'X': np.random.random(100) * 50 + 100, 'Y': np.random.random(100) * 250 + 500})
```

which looks like:

```
                X           Y
count  100.000000  100.000000
mean   126.183239  622.705947
std     15.766365   77.727067
min    100.574628  501.077603
25%    113.219299  545.146821
50%    125.318034  626.237368
75%    141.960502  694.636261
max    149.745984  749.947933
```

Use

```
df.plot.scatter('X', 'Y', xlim=(100, 150), ylim=(500, 750))
```

to get:[image]